# How can I find out which user groups my domain user belongs to?

Tags: windows-7, windows, domain, active-directory, user-groups

Running Windows 7 on my work PC, how can I check which groups I am a part of on the domain from my PC? I know how to check the local groups using MMC (Microsoft Management Console), just not the groups managed on the domain. I do not have remote access to our domain controller to check this, as we use a proprietary admin tool to access the server and licensing prevents additional installation.

Comment: Is it an Active Directory domain, or something else?

Comment: Active Directory, sorry

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Open a command prompt.

Type: `net user <userName> /domain`

It will list both Local and Global groups that user belongs to.

If you want it to only list the groups, you can use Find to filter it:

`net user <userName> /domain | find "Group"`

This has worked in all (NT) version of Windows since at least NT 4.

On Vista/2008 and above, you can also use `WhoAmI /Groups` to get a verbose list of group memberships (including their UIDs, etc.) for the current user.

Comment: nice. didn't know about this. FWIW it also works on 2008 R2 (not just Win7 as question is tagged with)

Comment: this worked, i also just found out that WHOAMI /GROUPS also shows more verbose information about the groups you are a member of as well

Comment: I forgot about WHOAMI /groups, Old habits I guess, the Net User command has been around since NT 4 days. :)  I'll add that to my answer to round it out.

Comment: this post is also useful http://serverfault.com/questions/49405/command-line-to-list-users-in-a-windows-active-directory-group shows how to get all the users in a group

Comment: This is not helpful, because the group names are truncated to 21 characters. A better solution, which also does not require extra software, is here http://serverfault.com/a/594724/66588

Comment: @Vistor Feel free to add an additional answer instead of claiming the existing answer is not helpful (18 people disagree ;) ) and just posting a link. The more answers the better. :)

Comment: Also the group list can span several lines but the find command only shows the first.